# Override 'on the fly' css rules selectors of a css file with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

I have a page containing a select tag that allow to change the css theme of the page "on the fly" with some javascript.

Now, I want to allow to change the css style for specifics html elements in the page.

By example, I have theses two 'theme' stylesheets :

```css
/* in red theme file 'theme_red.css' */
.title{color:red;}
.text{...}
```

```css
/* in blue theme file 'theme_blue.css' */
.title{color:blue;}
.text{...}
```

And I have some "select" tag "change theme" in the page. This is here a minimalist example, in a real case, the number of 'themable' html elements and the number of stylesheet are modular.

I'm looking for create a javascript function like this : (pure javascript ES6)

```js
loadCssThemeFileOnTheFlyForSpecificHtmlElement(idOfSpecificHtmlElement, themeName){
    // 1) Insert a new link tag in the head of the page with href attribute "themeName + '.css'"
    ...

    // 2) for each css rules selector (of the css file ?), override the css selector rule like this : 
    // `.selector1` become `#idOfElement .selector1`
    // `.selector2` become `#idOfElement .selector2`
    // ...
    // `.selectorN` become `#idOfElement .selectorN`

}
```

And I'm stuck in the step 2 of the function `insertCssFileOnTheFly`. Is it possible to do what I want to do with some javascript ?
I mean, is it possible to loop of the css rule of the current page and add to each selector rule the string "#idOfElement " ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: In the browser, jasvascript works with the DOM, not with the CSS file, you can not modify the CSS selectors in this way

Comment: Do you want to apply the "blue" theme to some elements on the page and the "red" theme to others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do what I want to do with some javascript ? I mean,
> is it possible to loop of the css rule of the current page and add to
> each selector rule the string "#idOfElement "?

Yes. Using javascript you can access and modify the contents of your stylesheets. For instance, if you have only one `StyleSheet`, you can reference it like this:

```
document.styleSheets[0]
```

Each `StyleSheet` has a `CSSRuleList` - an array-like object containing an ordered collection of `CSSRule` objects:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules
```

And each `CSSRule` has, amongst its properties, a `selectorText` property.

So, if you want to reference the `selectorText` of the **first** `CSSRule` of your **first** `StyleSheet`, you can use:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].selectorText // .selector1
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const myCSSRules = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;

for (let CSSRule of myCSSRules) {

  CSSRule.selectorText = '#my-element ' + CSSRule.selectorText;
  console.log(CSSRule.selectorText);

}
```

```css
.selector1 {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.selector2 {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<p class="selector1">Selector 1</p>
<p class="selector2">Selector 2</p>

<div style="border: 1px dashed red; text-align:center;" id="my-element">
  <p class="selector1">Selector 1</p>
  <p class="selector2">Selector 2</p>
</div>
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRuleList

Answer (score 1):

CSS can be removed or added on the fly using the `document.head.removeChild()` and `document.head.appendChild()` methods.

**To remove an existing css file on the fly:**

```
var redTheme = document.getElementById('red-theme-css')
document.head.removeChild(redTheme)
```

**To add a new css file on the fly:**

```
var blueTheme = document.createElement('link')
blueTheme.id = "blue-theme-css"
blueTheme.type = "text/css"
blueTheme.rel = "stylesheet"
blueTheme.href = "link-to-blue-theme-css-file"
document.head.appendChild(blueTheme)
```

The above method can be used either to change theme for the entire document, or for a specific component.

If the requirement is to change styling for only one component, then the css file to be loaded must be written in such a way that it has the classes that apply to the specific component only.

**More information:**

https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for your help ! but the question is not about removing an existing rule or add a new css file on the fly (I know how do that), the point here is how change the whole of a loaded (on the fly) css file by override its rules (change all rules likes '.selector1{}' by '#idOfSpecificElementGivenInJavascriptFunction .selector1{}' )

Comment: Loading a css file will apply the style at the document level, and it may possibly affect all the components. If the requirement is to apply css to specific element on the fly, by the means of loading css file, then the CSS file to be loaded must have classes that apply to the specific element only. If the css file to be loaded has a class that is used by multiple elements, then all those elements will get affected soon after the file gets loaded.